# TypeScript does not solve serialization and static type checking, how to do it then?

Tags: javascript, typescript, static-typing

This question is maybe already answered here, but I not found it.

TypeScript is transcribed into JavaScript, because of that there is zero static typechecking if I for example want to serialize JSON into object defined by type/interface.

I am rewriting an Server/Client application written in JavaScript (Node.js/React) into TypeScript and I am stuck on how to do better validation for REST API.

When I receive JSON from client (for example User model) I want to parse it into model. But compiled source will just ignore everything, so how to do it properly?

As I know, when developing in strongly typed languages big part of validation is made by defined interface... Or for example Java Spring needs also manual validation for "this field is required"? Or it just blow exception because it cant parse it into object?

Comment: My question is why do you expect a different model structure than what's defined during development? For runtime checking you'd have to validate the structure manually which defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Phix As I know, when developing in strongly typed languages big part of validation is made by defined interface... Or for example Java Spring needs also manual validation for "this field is required"? Or it just blow exception because it cant parse it into object?

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand what you're after.  When you are developing and have the expected types defined, the API response should be that type. Unit and E2E tests help here but if your API is returning something different than what's expected based on the TS type then.... I dunno. Sounds like a different issue entirely.

Comment: @Phix more then responses I am worried about requests... Because when sending request with for example form data I need to validate inputs and JSON schema. With JS you use some module for schema validation like AJV but with Typescript it must be easier am I right?

Comment: No, like you said TS compiles down to JS so all the typing is for development purposes. If you need to validate request data you'll need to do it by some other means, which you should do in some regard anyway as you shouldn't blindly accept user input.

Comment: @Phix thats sure thing, but I hoped that TypeScript will help reduce complexity of this valication process with usage of interfaces and types